# What's wrong with my c++ code? for a = 90 Z should be equal to -1, but I'm getting completly different answer. Why?

Tags: c++, trigonometry

I tried to make code that can calculate trigonometric function but it went wrong and i don't know what to do because I just can't see any mistakes

```
using namespace std;
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{`

    const double pi = M_PI;
    double Z, a, sin1, cos1, X, Y;

    //printf("Input a =");
    printf("%s", "Input a = ");
    scanf("%g", &a);
    a = a * pi / 180;
    sin1 = sin(3 * pi - 2 * a);
    X = (sin1 * sin1)*2;
    cos1 = cos(5 * pi - 2 * a);
    Y = cos1 * cos1;
    Z = X - Y;
    printf("Z = %g\n\n", Z);

    _getch();
    return 0;


}`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: `scanf("%g", &a);` translates into English as to *Read a `float` from the user and store it at the address of a `double`.* A nice compiler with a sufficient warning level will warn you about this, but unfortunately it is still legal code and the compiler has to respect your wishes it and give you a program that can't work. Demonstration: https://godbolt.org/z/oEc4YKh6n

Comment: The fix for that is use C++ IO `cin >> a;` makes sure all the types line up or it will not compile. It's easy to screw up `scanf`. I had to edit my above comment because I had the `double` and the `float` backward, and I've been doing this stuff for decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the above commments, enabling compiler warning messages should indicate the problem and suggest a solution, thus removing `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` may help to view the problem and solution:

```
(15,11): warning C4477: 'scanf' : format string '%g' requires an argument of type 'float *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'double *'
(15,11): message : consider using '%lg' in the format string
(15,5): error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

When using the compiler suggestion:

```
scanf("%lg", &a);
```

as also mentioned in the above comments, we still get a warning regarding use of `scanf`:

```
(15,5): error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

So, to keep using `scanf` when we include `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` and get expected output, however using the compiler suggested `scanf_s` (and remove `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`) also produces expected output.

However, since you've included `iostream`, c++ provides the `cin` object of class iostream, thus the simplest solution may be to use `cin` as suggested in the above comment.

Comment: And the fun thing about `scanf_s` is it's only safer for certain definitions of safer. Personally I find those definitions to be light on safety.